# C# Send responsive HTML mail using media queries

Tags: c#, css, responsive

I have HTML template format for email which i am using to send email from C# desktop application. Now I am trying to below media query but it is not working

```html
<html> <style> @viewport {width: device-width;}@media screen and (min-width: 200px) and (max-width: 800px) { #navigateTop {background-color:orange;}  }@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 2800px) { #navigateTop {background-color:#9A0018;}  } </style>
<table width='2600' border = 0 cellspacing = 0 cellpadding = 0><tr><td colspan = 5>
<table id = 'navigateTop' width = '100%' border = 0 cellspacing = 0 cellpadding = 10 style = 'color: white; font: 20px Segoe UI;' >
 <tr>
  <td>Company Name<span style = 'font: 12px Segoe UI;'>(From Dec 2017)</span></td>
  <td rowspan = 3 style = 'font: 40px Segoe UI Light;'>Update</td>
  <td rowspan = 3><img width = 120 style = 'width:1.25in' src = 'somelink.png'></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>$0</td>
 </tr>
</table></td></tr>
</table>

</html>
```

If i copy the generated HTML before sending mail and run as .html page in browser, then able to see the media query effect. But in Outlook the effects are not working. Any idea on how to insert media queries in C#?

Comment: You might need to post a little bit more code than that to get a helpful answer. What have you already tried?

Comment: What version of Outlook are you using?

Comment: I am using Outlook 2016 latest version

Comment: @DavidKemp Edited the post with complete code. That code is working in browser, not in Outlook. I tried adding @@ instead of single @ before viewport and media.. but that is also not working

Answer (score 2):

According to [Campaign Monitor](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/media-queries/media/), media queries aren't supported in Outlook 2007-2016.

They also have a [helpful tool](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/properties/media-queries/) to show which clients support which media queries

Answer (score 0):

Outlook does not support responsive templates.
https://emailmonks.com/blog/email-coding/email-rendering-issues-in-outlook-and-hacks/